# Angular 10 Flex Layout + Material design components

Tags: angular, flexbox

I have the following layout but I'm struggling with with how to lay it out using Flex layout and Angular components with Angular material components as the GUI elements

[image: Sample Layout]

Lets suppose it's broken up into the following components

- Part with picture to the left middle is one component - lets call it view-component
- Part to the right middle holding the tabs  = lets call it side nav
- The side nav is an angular material tab - each has it's own component - lets call them each sidenav1, sidenav2 sidenav3 components
- Header part is just a material header - this seems to be behaving fine

So I have the following questions

- I want the application to behave more like a desktop application so I don't want any scrolling bars on the main window. How do I do this?
- How do I limit the size of the view-component to be no more than 2/3 the width. How do I deal with the height? The image that goes inside this component can be different resolutions but I need what is shown always to be consistent in both height and width?
- How do I add scrollbars to **just** sidenav1, saidenav2 etc.. if the amount of content is greater than the height of the window
- I need to split one of the sidenav tabs in two sections, giving each it's own scroll bar if the data overflows the respective section. Again not sure how best to do this
- In general what is the best approach to putting an angular component inside a 'Flex container'

I normally do something like this code wise

```
<div class="container" fxLayoutGap="30px" fxLayout="row"  >      
    <div *ngIf="isViewCAD"  class="child-1" fxFlex="1 1 0"  >
        <app-part-view></app-part-view>                           
    </div> 
    
    <div *ngIf="isViewImage" class="child-2" fxFlex="1 1 0"  >        
        <app-image-view></app-image-view>         
    </div> 

    <div class="child-3" fxFlex="1 1 30" >
        <app-part-side-nav></app-part-side-nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ideally I would like to accomplish most of this with just Flex layout and use as little as possible css. (No idea if that is possible) I'd like to keep this all as simple as possible

So really I am looking for how to lay this all out at a very high level with Flex layout. I have most of the components coded up but it's not a very consistent experience for a user from a layout point of view